# Connection to the another DB not created by Django

Tags: python, django

I have `Django` project and want to look the another db (not default db created by `Php Symfony`)

Django can set up two DB in `settins.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT"),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
    }

    'extern': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config("DB_EXTERN_NAME"),
        'USER': config("DB_EXTERN_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': config("DB_EXTERN_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': config("DB_EXTERN_HOST"),
        'PORT': config("DB_EXTERN_PORT"),
    }
}
```

and set `models.py` for example

```
class Area(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_area'
```

However it requires to change the extern database when `python manage.py makemigrations`,`python manage.py migrate`

I just want to reference the extern db not alter.

Is there any good practice??

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the [`managed = false`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed) meta setting on your models. That will cause Django not to try to manage those models (such as creating migrations for them). It's commonly used when working with externally managed databases.

EG:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_area'
        managed = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to generate your models using

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=extern > models.py
```

This will generate models corresponding to the tables in your database

Check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/) for more details about legacy databases (django docs)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need do is run

```
python manage.py migrate --database extern
```